# Service bus request and response pattern for Topic

Tags: servicebus

WE have a requirement to publish an event which will be subscribed by multiple subscribers. Each subscriber in turn will return the response for the message.

We are trying to use on-premise windows service bus for this.
This link https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Brokered-Messaging-Request-0ce8fcaf covers the request and response pattern for queues. But I am looking for request/response pattern from multiple subscribers using Topics.

I could not find any reference on this.

Could you please suggest an approach to implement this.

Comment: I'm implementing something similar using Azure Service Bus. How did you finally do? Any advice?